# Upload image to Servlet and then forward to Amazon s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, servlets, amazon-s3

I'm having trouble processing the image I upload to the server. Looking around online, it seems to me that I need to first create a `DiskFileItemFactory` object from the apache library, then I create a `ServletFileUpload` object. From there I loop through all the form items until I hit the file. However, when I do `formItems.iterator()` the compliler complains

```
- Iterator is a raw type. References to generic type Iterator<E> should be 
     parameterized
    - The method iterator() is undefined for the type List
```

How would I go about fixing this error, and could someone help me learn what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to Java Servlets, but am familiar with Java. Here's my code below. Thanks!

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //doGet(request, response);

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXX", "XXXX");

        AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

        try {

        out.println("Hello, THIS WORKED!!<br/>");

             boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);


             if (isMultipart) {
                    out.println("Multipart is true");

                      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
                        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
                        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");

                        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                        factory.setSizeThreshold(THRESHOLD_SIZE);

                        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                        upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
                        upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);


                        List formItems = (List) upload.parseRequest(request);

/////COMPILER ERROR. It complains that the Iterator is a raw type. How Do I learn how to fix this? 
                        Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();



                        // iterates over form's fields to get UUID Value
                        while (iter.hasNext()) {
                            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                            ObjectMetadata om = new ObjectMetadata();
                            om.setContentLength(item.getSize());

                            try {



                            } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) { 
                                out.println(ase.toString());

                            } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {


                                out.println(ace.toString());
                            }


                            s3Client.putObject("images", "TestImg.jpg", item.getInputStream(), om);
                            if (item.isFormField()) {

                            out.println(item.getString());

                            }
                            // processes only fields that are not form fields
                            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                               // itemFile = item;
                            }
                        }


//                      
//                  }
//                  

             }


        } catch(Exception e) {



            out.print(e.toString());

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a step back and try to tackle this step-by-step. Forget about all the AWS stuff for now, because you aren't even getting to the point in your code where you are interacting with AWS. You need to first get the file upload working before you should worry about copying the file to S3. To do that you need to figure out what the compiler is telling you.

Let's look at these two lines:

```
List formItems = (List) upload.parseRequest(request);
Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();
```

Looking a few lines up we see that `upload` is an instance of `ServletFileUpload`. So let's go to [the documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html#parseRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-) for `ServletFileUpload.parseRequest()`. The documentation shows this method signature:

```
public List<FileItem> parseRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
                            throws FileUploadException
```

Notice how it doesn't just return a `List` object, it actually returns a `List<FileItem>` object. When you were casting it to `(List)` you were throwing that information away. So let's change the code to use `FileItem` and while we're at it, why not use a [Java For-Each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) instead of an old-school `Iterator` like so:

```
List<FileItem> formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
for (FileItem item : formItems) {
    ObjectMetadata om = new ObjectMetadata();
    om.setContentLength(item.getSize());
```